# CropResolutionPolicy and AdMob in andEngine not working together

Tags: android, admob, andengine, screen-resolution

I try to show ads in my game.
Here is a method I use to do that:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//public void onSetContentView(){

    //super.onSetContentView();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.adView = new AdView(this);
    this.adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    this.adView.setY(50);

    this.adView.setAdUnitId("here goes my id");

    com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adrequest = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

    this.adView.loadAd(adrequest);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



    layout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView);
    layout.addView(this.adView, params);



}
```

and XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id ="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.hsdev.salesrep.MainActivity" >
```

Without layout and ad cropresolution policy woked very good. But after adding layout it is stretched a bit. Also when I tried to change it to RatioResolutionPolicy it was alligned to the left (in horizontal view, the margin was only on right side, and not on both like it is normally in andEngine). So question is: How can I use layout (because I want to show ad, and still use resoltion policies from andEngine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so answer is simple...Just need to set gravity.:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id ="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="com.hsdev.salesrep.MainActivity" >
</RelativeLayout>
```